# What does offset = 0 does here?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read input sent from arduino as "Hello".
But in my application it is only printing "ello".
The '0' in the statement represents offset.
The question is does this method starts reading from starting of the message or
does it reads after the first character (H), what does offset does here ??
Statement is:

```
readMessage = new String(buffer,0,bytes);
```

Comment: What is `bytes`? Is this Arduino or Android? Is this Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Using this constructor you are using *buffer* from *byte 0* (inclusive) to *bytes* (exclusive) to create a String from it. So using this method you can create a string using a part of the buffer.